# xmodmap Right CTRL to work as Right SHIFT

Tags: xmodmap

I've tried searching a lot with no success. I know this can be done because I have done it before, but since then I've reinstalled the OS.

I know that I used xmodmap to do this the last time.

My reasoning for this is because both shift keys are broken on my laptop so I've trained myself to use right-ctrl as right-shift.

I know that my laptop has right-ctrl as `keycode 105`. As far as I can tell left shift is `keycode 50` and right shift is `keycode 62`.

I've tried doing the following things:

`xmodmap -e 'keycode 105 = Shift_R'` (this shows the right-ctrl key as being right-shift under xev but pressing it actually does nothing)

`xmodmap -e 'keycode 105 = 62'` (this outputs `>`)

`xmodmap -e 'keycode 105 = 50'` (this outputs `2`)

Can someone please show me what I need to do in order to make this work and make it work as a permanent change? This is an unusable OS for me until I can do this. I manged this in Windows in just a few minutes! :(

Answer (score -1):

In order to edit a special key/signal, you have to clear it in the beginning of `~/.Xmodmap`. For example:

```
clear Shift_R
```

and then add the new signals at the end of `~/.Xmodmap`. It may be helpful: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap

Write your expressions in `~/.Xmodmap` to make the changes permanent.

Comment: Clear will only accept `clear Shift`. You can then do whatever is require later on in de xmodmap. `clear Shift_R` will throw an error (bad modifier name).